# FullCalendar não aparece barra de navegação

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Estou usando o plugin FullCalendar, ele lista eventos corretamente mas somente não exibe a barra de navegação. no console não aparecem erros de javascript. Olhando o Inpecionar Elemento observei que os botões são gerados mas ainda sim ficam invisiveis.
Não encontrei nenhum erro no css, em conjunto estou utilizado o tema bootstrap Admin Light Dashboard da Creative Tim.
Se alguém puder dar uma força agradeço.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            right: 'prev,next,today'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-11-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow more link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-11-01',
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2017-11-07',
                end: '2017-11-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-11-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-11-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2017-11-11',
                end: '2017-11-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-11-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2017-11-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2017-11-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-11-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2017-11-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2017-11-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2017-11-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2017-11-28'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Poste o código para obter maior ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás a incluir as *libs* necessárias? Verifica abaixo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
            right: 'prev,next,today'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-11-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow more link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-11-01',
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2017-11-07',
                end: '2017-11-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-11-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2017-11-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2017-11-11',
                end: '2017-11-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-11-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2017-11-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2017-11-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2017-11-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2017-11-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2017-11-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2017-11-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2017-11-28'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Os links não funcionaram, mas sua ajuda me abriu os olhos para revisar o CSS do FullCalendar. Adicionei a propriedade display:block e tudo voltou ao normal.